# Reactiveui bind not working for SeekBar.Progress

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I'm trying to learn reactiveui so I wanted to make simple tip calculator app for android. 
The ViewModel is:

```
public class TipCalcViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [IgnoreDataMember] private double _subtotal;

    [DataMember]
    public double Subtotal
    {
        get { return _subtotal; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _subtotal, value); }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember] private int _percentage;

    [DataMember]
    public int Percentage
    {
        get { return _percentage; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _percentage, value); }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember] private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<double> _tipAmount;

    [DataMember]
    public double TipAmount
    {
        get { return _tipAmount.Value; }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember] private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<double> _total;

    [DataMember]
    public double Total
    {
        get { return _total.Value; }
    }

    public TipCalcViewModel(ITipCalcService service)
    {
        _tipAmount = this.WhenAnyValue(
            x => x.Subtotal,
            y => y.Percentage,
            service.CalculateTipAmount)
            .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.TipAmount);

        _total = this.WhenAnyValue(
            x => x.Subtotal,
            y => y.Percentage,
            service.CalculateTotal)
            .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.Total);
    }
}
```

And Activity looks like this:

```
public class TipCalcActivity : ReactiveActivity<TipCalcViewModel>
{
    public EditText SubTotal { get { return this.GetControl<EditText>(); } }
    public SeekBar Percentage { get { return this.GetControl<SeekBar>(); } }
    public TextView PercentageText { get { return this.GetControl<TextView>(); } }
    public TextView TipAmount { get { return this.GetControl<TextView>(); } }
    public TextView Total { get { return this.GetControl<TextView>(); } }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var service = new TipCalcService();
        ViewModel = new TipCalcViewModel(service);

        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Subtotal, v => v.SubTotal.Text);
        //this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Percentage, v => v.Percentage.Progress);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Percentage, v => v.PercentageText.Text);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.TipAmount, v => v.TipAmount.Text);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Total, v => v.Total.Text);

        var disposable = Observable.FromEventPattern<SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs>(
            h => Percentage.ProgressChanged += h,
            h => Percentage.ProgressChanged -= h)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Subscribe(x => 
                ViewModel.Percentage = x.EventArgs.Progress);
    }
}
```

So questions:

- If I use above commented binding nothing happens. So progress property is changing correctly but Percentage property of ViewModel is never being set. Binding is working from viewmodel to the view but not other way around (EditText binding is working fine in both directions). How to fix this?
- I managed to make it work if I create observable from ProgressChanged event. But even if I had to do something like this I'm not sure if this is the correct way. Also do I have to dispose the subscription when activity is destroyed manualy or not?
- And last thing. If I wanted to learn this framework what is the best way to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SeekBar is most likely not in the list of supported out-of-the-box controls; Android has no built-in way to observe view properties, so we have to hard-code them as one-offs. You can make this work if you write something like:

```
var progressChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs>(
        h => Percentage.ProgressChanged += h,
        h => Percentage.ProgressChanged -= h);

this.Bind(ViewModel, 
    vm => vm.Percentage, 
    v => v.Percentage.Progress, 
    signalViewUpdate: progressChanged);
```